# how to apply RDP session timeouts to a local group in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, remote-desktop

Windows 2008 R2 64-bit, not a member of Active Directory.  Created local group named RDP_Session_Settings.  The group has a number of local users in it, but not all local users that exist on that server.

How can the User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Session Time Limits settings to applied to that group?

I tried to launch MMC -> Add Remove SnapIn -> Group Policy Object but the RDP_Session_Settings group is not an available choice.  Only Administrators and Non-Administrators are listed as groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MLGPO can be applied to Administrators, Non-Administrators or to individual users, but not to any other local group. If you want these settings to apply to individual users who are Non-Administrators but not to all of the users who are Non-Administrators then you're going to have to create a LGPO for each of those users. Note that you can add all of the users to a single MMC console and edit them at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that this may be the case.  Not quite as convenient as I hoped it to be but it will do.

Comment: Glad to help...